# Evaluate the limit of $\sum\limits _ { k = 0} ^ { n } \mathrm{arctg} \frac { k + 1} { n ^ { 2} }$ when $n\to\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Evaluate $$\lim _ { n \rightarrow \infty } \sum _ { k = 0} ^ { n } \mathrm{arctg} \frac { k + 1} { n ^ { 2} }$$

At first I thought this was a Riemann sum, but I couldn't insert the $1/n$ and get the right form. I also tried to write it out, and it definitely looks like it would converge, but I'm not sure how to approach it.

Comment: Using the double inequality $$x-x^3\leqslant\arctan x\leqslant x$$ say, for every $x$ in $(0,1)$, should be enough to show your sum is $$\frac12+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$$

Comment: I get $\frac{1}{2}$ as a result, but I did it in a hacky way.

Comment: @Did thank you, I didn't consider the expansion for arctan.

Comment: Yes. Note however that I do not suggest to rely on asymptotic expansions but on true, "hard", inequalities, valid for every $x$ in $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

First, recall that

$$\arctan(x)=x+O(x^3)$$

as $x\to 0$.

Then, we have

$$\arctan\left(\frac{k+1}{n^2}\right)=\frac{k+1}{n^2}+O\left(\frac{(k+1)^3}{n^6}\right)$$

as $\frac{k+1}{n^2}\le \frac{n+1}{n^2}\to 0$.

Since $\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^3=O(n^4)$, only the linear term contributes in the limit as $n\to \infty$.  Therefore,

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\arctan\left(\frac{k+1}{n^2}\right)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\frac{k+1}{n^2}\right)=\frac12$$

Comment: Hmmm... Maybe add that the furthestpoint  away from $0$ where one uses the expansion is $(n+1)/n^2$, which indeed goes to $0$ when $n\to\infty$ hence all is well.

Comment: @did Didier, doesn't the Big O notation cover all terms past the leading one here?

Comment: Big-O at $0$ rules what happens in an unspecified neighborhood $V$ of $0$. To be sure that one uses the expansion at points $x_{k,n}$ that are all in $V$ for $n$ large enough, a common argument is to show that $\sup\limits_k|x_{k,n}|\to0$ (which is the case here, for the reason I gave).

Comment: @Did Yes, the largest the argument can become is $\frac{n+1}{n^2}\to 0$.  So, the Big-O at $0$ prevails.  Is that all you'd like to see added here?

Comment: @Did I've edited accordingly.  Thank you, as always, for the constructive comments.

Comment: Good post, +1. $ $

Comment: @Did Thank you; much appreciative of your help!

Answer (score 0):

Set $\dfrac{1}{n^2} = m$

We get $\arctan\left(\dfrac{k+1}{n^2}\right)=\arctan\left((k+1) m^2\right)$

Using MacLaurin series we have

$\arctan\left((k+1) m^2\right)=(k+1) m^2+O\left(m^6\right)$

that is 
$$\arctan\left(\dfrac{k+1}{n^2}\right)\approx \dfrac{k+1}{n^2}$$

which means that 
$$\sum _{k=0}^n \arctan\left(\frac{k+1}{n^2}\right)\approx\sum _{k=0}^n \frac{k+1}{n^2},\text{ as }n\to\infty$$

as 
$$\sum _{k=0}^n (k+1)=\frac{1}{2} (n+1) (n+2)$$
we have
$$\sum _{k=0}^n \frac{k+1}{n^2}=\frac{(n+1) (n+2)}{2 n^2}$$
and
$$\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \frac{(n+1) (n+2)}{2 n^2}=\frac{1}{2}$$